# Protractor can't find element.

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, protractor

Any idea how to click element, `src="/images/mediaMicroThumbnail/9949436.jpeg"` ?

I tried to click by CSS and by xpath but it's not working.  After click element should be selected but it isn't.

```html
<div class="as-sortable-item img-thumbnail ng-scope" ng-class="{ 'x-img-selected': image.selected }" ng-repeat="image in images | orderBy:'createDate':true" ng-click="selectImage(image)">
                        <div class="remove-item">
                            <button class="close" ng-click="removeImage(image)" ng-disabled="removingDisabled">×</button>
                        </div>
                        <img ng-src="/images/mediaMicroThumbnail/9949436.jpeg" src="/images/mediaMicroThumbnail/9949436.jpeg">
                    </div>
```

Comment: Will the src remain same everytime? may be the name of the jpeg file .. are you looking to click the img element based on its src?

Comment: No, src will be de diffrent everytime. And i tried to locate by src,  but i does'n work

Comment: Then you can identify `img` element by any unique parent/neighbour .. In your case .. you can get the `img` through parent `div`  - `element(by.css('.img-thumbnail img'))`